# execute a number of batch commands for each files at one time

Tags: loops, batch-file

How do I execute a number of batch commands for a number of files one by one. Meaning, say, if I want to first move a file from one folder to a working folder, rename the file to a csv format, call a sqlloader script, call second sql script and finally call another sql script - all steps above should not be for all the files, but for one file at a time. I tried something like this as below, but getting error as "\Downloads\Validation\Prestage*.psa) was unexpected at this time." Can't I pass a wildcard *.psa in the loop criteria?

Thanks much and appreciate for your time on this.

```
    echo off

    :MAIN


    copy C:\Downloads\Prevalidation\*.psa C:\Downloads\Validation\Prestage\

    FOR %A IN (C:\Downloads\Validation\Prestage\*.psa) DO ( move C:\Downloads\Validation\Prestage\*.psa C:\Downloads\Validation\WIP\
      ren C:\Downloads\Validation\WIP\*.psa *.csv
    <call sqlloader now>
    <call update script now> 
    <call validation script now> 
   )

   exit
```

Thanks,
Sanders.

Answer (score 0):

Your strategy is correct.

There is one minor syntactic error: You need to use `%%A` instead of `%A` in a `FOR` command inside a BAT file. And then you need to refer to `%%A` inside the loop as the name of the file being processed.

```
@echo off
copy C:\Downloads\Prevalidation\*.psa C:\Downloads\Validation\Prestage\
FOR %%A IN (C:\Downloads\Validation\Prestage\*.psa) DO ( 
  move %%A C:\Downloads\Validation\WIP\%%~nA.psa
  ren C:\Downloads\Validation\WIP\%%~nA.psa *.csv
  <call sqlloader now>
  <call update script now> 
  <call validation script now> 
)
```

Comment: PA - thanks for your response. However, I am still getting syntax error while executing the script. Heres my script -                 echo off

:MAIN
copy C:\Downloads\Prevalidation\*.psa C:\Downloads\Validation\Prestage\

FOR %%A IN (C:\Downloads\Validation\Prestage\*.psa) DO ( 
move %%A C:\Downloads\Validation\WIP\%%~nA.psa
ren C:\Downloads\Validation\WIP\%%~nA.psa psaload.csv
call C:\CAP_SPS\Batchscripts\runloader.bat
call C:\CAP_SPS\Batchscripts\runupdate.bat
call C:\CAP_SPS\Batchscripts\runvalidation.bat
del C:\Downloads\Validation\WIP\psaload.csv 
)
exit

Comment: @user982201: I would recommend using quotation marks around names in the `move` and the `ren` commands, like `move "%%A" "C:\Downloads\Validation\WIP\%%~nA.psa"`.

Comment: @user98822 which command is failing?... prefix all of your commands with echo and add quotes around the file names.

Comment: PA - it is failing while renaming the file. The error message being "The syntax of the command is incorrect". And I think i know the reason why. The above loop is not working as wanted. It is moving all the *.psa files from the Prestage folder to the WIP folder and then the program doesnt understand which file to rename to since I am passing on a single target file name to run my loader script and other scripts following it. So, back to my first question - how do I run the series of commands for each file present in a folder location instead of all at once?